# How to use babel-runtime transform without an external dependency?

Tags: babeljs

If I use the `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` plugin, then my code will `import`/`require` `babel-runtime` instead of including all those helper functions inline. This is nice, but it makes my library have a dependency `babel-runtime`. What I would rather do is have Babel extract one extra file (`./babel-runtime`) and drop that in with the other output files so that I don't have to include it as an *external* dependency. i.e., I won't have to add that to `package.json` everywhere my library is used. Is this possible?

Comment: Wouldn't bundling your code with webpack or Rollup solve this problem?

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski Well I don't want to pre-webpack it. The idea is to distribute my library as ES6 modules so that consumers can tree-shake it. Not sure how rollup avoids the runtime dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can import custom module instead of `babel-runtime` by using the `moduleName` option in the `transform-runtime` plugin:

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "moduleName": "./babel-runtime"
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Module path will get broken if my library directory structure isn't flat. Also, do you recommend copying `babel-runtime` out of my `node_modules` and into my dist then, or what?

Comment: @mpen Yes; you said that you don't want to use `babel-runtime` as an external dependency, so this way you can use it as a local module. But maybe I misunderstood your question. Can you explain what you're actually trying to achieve? What's wrong with including `babel-runtime` as an external dependency?

Comment: If I write a library and it depends on babel-runtime, then anyone who uses my library has to install it too. I guess it becomes a "peer dependency". I don't want any dependencies in my little utility library. If it were a monolithic project, sure, a few extra deps isn't a big deal, but for a small set of helper functions, that's no good. Imagine if lodash needed babel-runtime.

Comment: @mpen People will need to download it for development, but they won't need to download multiple copies of it, because npm handles duplicate dependencies; and if they use tree shaking, only a small, relevant part of `babel-runtime` will end up in the production bundle.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found was to *not* use the `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` plugin and add `exclude: ['transform-regenerator']` to your config. This will prevent Babel from adding a dependency on regenerator. It also means your code won't run in older browsers.

If you need support for older browsers, you can try `fast-async`. It says there's a way to inline the dependency in just your index file, but I haven't tried it yet. I believe this assumes the browser supports Promises but not async/await.